# call stack showing anonymous function

Tags: javascript

I am a newbie to Javascript. i read that in debugging window the call stack means the functions that have been executed.
here is my code

```
    function myNameFunc(myNmae) {
    var myFullName = myNmae + " Singh";
    return myFullName;
}

var ok = myNameFunc('Adidas');
console.log(ok);
```

Now debugging through code when i have set the breakpoint to

```
var myFullName = myNmae + " Singh";
```

And when i step out of code the debugger says **Anonymous function** in call stack.
I do not get it... there should be the `myNameFun()c` in the call stack.. No??
Please tell me what i going on.
thanks.
[image]

Comment: Show the full call stack. `myNameFunc` must be the last one in your stack. However, there can be **absolutely any** functions after it - it is up to browser implementation and your other code.

Comment: @Added a Picture. see my question..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the point you've put the breakpoint `myNmaeFunc` has been called and returned

`myNameFunc` will no longer be on the call stack - it's finished, done with, over

The `anonymous func` is the main execution thread of the page

do a `console.error('inside')` within the function and a `console.error('done')` outside it - console.error shows a call stack at the point of the call ...